# Draw centered in form on moving image

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to implement a small tool that draws sin and cos functions. The program is supposed to draw from the center of the form, so that the history will extend to the right. Imagine the following gif but with the right end of the line moving up and down, and the path to the left "showing the trace"

[image]

What I would like to do is, every time a timer elapses, draw a point (via `Graphics.FillRectangle`) in the center of a `PictureBox`. In the next timer fire move the graphics one pixel to the left, and draw the next pixel. This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  bmp = New Drawing.Bitmap(PictureBox1.Size.Width, PictureBox1.Size.Height)
  g1 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

  MathTimer = New Timers.Timer(30)
  AddHandler MathTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
  MathTimer.Enabled = True
  MathTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
  g1.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, PictureBox1.Size.Width \ 2, PictureBox1.Size.Height \ 2, 1, 1)
  g1.TranslateTransform(-1, 0)
  PictureBox1.Image = bmp
End Sub
```

However, this doesn't achieve the desired effect, since the canvas of the graphics object `g1` is moved to the left with this. Eventually it's not drawing anymore. (No wonder, since with this I'm drawing "with the left end of the line")

Anybody have a better idea that achieves the desired effect?

Comment: What abouit time? What should happen when the first points reach the left edge?

Comment: They should be destroyed. What matters is the recent history, emerging from the right end of the line in the center

Comment: ok. and what about the right half? shall it stay empty? - I don't think, unless other things come along, that drawing this into a bitmap is a good way. instead 1) collect the coordinates in a List<Point> 2) draw them all with a growing negative offset in the Paint event c) once you have enouh points to reach the left edge remove the 1st point when adding a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To pointsToDraw.Count - 2
    Dim p As Point = pointsToDraw(i)
    Dim xPos As Integer = (pctrBxSinCosDraw.Width / 2) + p.X - currentTick
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, xPos, CInt(p.Y + pctrBxSinCosDraw.Height / 2), 1, 1)
    If xPos <= 0 Then
        pointsToDraw.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

Where `currentTick` is set by a `Timer`, which on `Tick`, calculates the x/y values:

```
Dim yVal As Double
If useSinCalc Then
    yVal = Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(currentTick)) * (180 / Math.PI)
Else
    yVal = Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(currentTick)) * (180 / Math.PI)
End If
pointsToDraw.Add(New Point(currentTick, yVal))
currentTick += 1
pctrBxSinCosDraw.Invalidate()
```

And `DegreeToRadian` simply does (as it states):

```
Private Function DegreeToRadian(ByVal angle As Double)
    DegreeToRadian = Math.PI * angle / 180.0
End Function
```

And `pointsToDraw` is `List(Of Point)`

A sample project can be found [on my download page.](http://blog.abouchleih.com/wp-content/uploads/SOQuestion44765839.7z)